# how to insert data in database using tinymce

Tags: php, tinymce

This are my codes for `TinyMCE`, when I intend to submit it doesn't appear on the database and what datatype should I put in the table:

```
< CONNECTION TO DATABASE?>

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>

<!-- Load TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
});
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="insert" method="post" action="insert.php">

        <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%" class="tinymce">

        </textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Some integration calls -->
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().show();return false;">[Show]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().hide();return false;">[Hide]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('Bold');return false;">[Bold]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').html());return false;">[Get contents]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getContent());return false;">[Get selected HTML]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));return false;">[Get selected text]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert($('#elm1').tinymce().selection.getNode().nodeName);return false;">[Get selected element]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<b>Hello world!!</b>');return false;">[Insert HTML]</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#elm1').tinymce().execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<b>{$selection}</b>');return false;">[Replace selection]</a>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.location.protocol == 'file:') {
alert("The examples might not work properly on the local file system due to security   settings in your browser. Please use a real webserver.");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the codes for the `insert.php`:

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$content = $_POST['elm1'];



$insertSQL="INSERT INTO table (content) VALUES ('".$content."')";

if (!mysql_query($insertSQL,$db_server)) echo "Insert failed: $insertSQL <br />".
mysql_error()."<br /><br />";

header("Location:index.php");  
?>
```

What am I supposed to do? Need help, Thanks a lot

Comment: You really should refrain from caps locks when asking questions.

Comment: YOU SHOULD KNOW YOU LEAVE YOURSELF WIDE OPEN TO TO SQL INJECTIONS.

Answer (score 2):

this is wrong:

```
$insertSQL="INSERT INTO table (content) VALUES ('".$content."')";
```

do it like :

```
$insertSQL=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (content) VALUES ('$content')");
```

Comment: also i hope this is the jquery adress <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> or it tinymce won't work

Comment: what datatype should i use for the content?

Comment: for textarea, simply make it text or varchar either one works

Comment: But be sure to escape it! see [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Although you REALLY should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

Comment: can you give me another rich text editor, cause it seems like tinymce didnt work well.